# Finding the land plot for a (lat,long) coordinate

Tags: c#, oracle, geocoding, latitude-longitude, reverse-geocoding

I am using Oracle database consisting of details of land plots and their latitude and longitude coordinates. The plots have basically three/four corners. My main objective is to search if inside any of the plots mentioned in database, a random (latitude,longitude) coordinate falls or not?

Am I going the right way by constructing a kD Tree of (lat,long) coordinates?

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: A row consists of land_no, lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, lat3, lon3, lat4, lon4(for four corners). Latitude and longitude are in xx.yyyyyy form.

Comment: are the four corners always correctly specified in terms of order, or does th query also have to work out which one is top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right? For rows where only 3 corners specified - are they triangles, or must the query invent the missing 4th to make a rectangle?

Comment: There is no order for the corners. For rows with three corners, the land is triangle shaped and the fourth coordinates are (0.000000,0.000000).